# compare dict.keys() with list, bug in expression

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to compare each dictionary key with a values from list:

```
order = {
    u'custom_attributes_desc': {u'text': u'Food truck', u'name': u'Bob', u'email': u'bob@yahoo.com'}, 
    u'account_id': 12345, 
    u'state_desc': u'open', 
    u'start_dt': u'2013-07-25 15:41:37', 
    u'end_dt': u'2013-07-25 19:41:37', 
    u'product_nm': u'foo', 
    u'transaction_id': 12345, 
    u'product_id': 1111
}
match = ['transaction_id', 'account_id', 'product_nm']
not_matched_keys = [key_match for key_order, key_match in zip(order.keys(),match) if key_order != key_match]
```

And result I'm getting:

```
not_matched_keys
['transaction_id', 'account_id', 'product_nm']
```

But I would like to see

```
[]
```

Because matched keys are in dictionary.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Dictionaries have no set order, so you do *not* know what keys are matched up with elements from `match`.

Comment: I'm trying to compare if key in dict is in list. And it shouldn't return anything. But I have some bug in my expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to list keys taken from `match` that are *not* present in the dictionary, use a list comprehension:

```
not_matched_keys = [key for key in match if key not in order]
```

Your code created 3 pairs, one of each of the elements in `match`, with 3 *arbitrary* keys from `order`. If those three arbitrary keys happen to not be equal to the 3 values from `match` they all are included in your output:

```
>>> order = {u'custom_attributes_desc': {u'text': u'Food truck', u'name': u'Bob', u'email': u'bob@yahoo.com'}, u'account_id': 12345, u'state_desc': u'open', u'start_dt': u'2013-07-25 15:41:37', u'end_dt': u'2013-07-25 19:41:37', u'product_nm': u'foo', u'transaction_id': 12345, u'product_id': 1111}
>>> match = ['transaction_id', 'account_id', 'product_nm']
>>> list(zip(match, order.keys()))
[('transaction_id', 'end_dt'), ('account_id', 'product_id'), ('product_nm', 'transaction_id')]
```

Comment: I see, that explains everything!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `filter()` here.

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x not in order, not_matched_keys)
[]
```